# Ember-cli 0.2.5 livereload keeps reloading in every change

Tags: ember-cli

After updating to ember-cli 0.2.5 (same think with 0.2.4; 0.2.3 was ok), when i make a change to a file and save it, it keeps reloading my app at least 3 times for each save i do. Server's console shows `file added... file added... file added...` for all my app files each time, but my tmp folder is always empty. Also is seems that for each reload it tries to create a folder inside tmp folder, but it quickly removes it every time. The only file inside tmp folder is `.metadata_never_index`. Does this have to do with caching? Any help? I'm on yosemite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem with watchman 3.1.0 (which is the version that Homebrew installs) so I upgraded to 3.1.1 and it seems to have been resolved.

You'll need to install it from source, but it's easy:

```
$ brew uninstall watchman
```

Then just

```
$ git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
$ cd watchman
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

Fingers crossed it seems to have worked so far (thank goodness, as it was driving me CRAZY).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that has the same problem, i reinstall node and watchman and now everything seems to work fine.

**UPDATE I**

It seems that the problem still exists. I have to mension that i'm using sublime text 3. When i restart sublime it seems ok, but after a save it starts reloading again and again. Anyone can help here?

**UPDATE II**

Removed watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher and all seems ok. But time to time i need to restart sublime text in order to boot up the ember-cli server. That seems to be a known [issue](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/2683)...